# MVC return Json result to same View from I call Action

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I really need help with my code. Basically, I call the action from view through ajax and action returns string - this part works well. The problem is that action return result in new view. I don't want to happen. I want that string result to return to the original view which I called the action from. My code for script looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="LDR">
        <a class="Like" onmouseover="Like(@comment.Id)" onmouseout="ResetLike(@comment.Id)" onclick="LikeClick(@comment.Id)">
            <img src="~/Content/Style/img/Like.png" id="Like_@comment.Id" />
            @Html.Action("LikeComment", "Routes", new { id = comment.Id })
        </a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("AddDislikeComment", "Routes", new {id = comment.Id})" class="Dislike" onmouseover="Dislike(@comment.Id)" onmouseout="ResetDislike(@comment.Id)">
            <img src="~/Content/Style/img/Dislike.png" id="Dislike_@comment.Id" />
            @Html.Action("DislikeComment", "Routes", new { id = comment.Id })
        </a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("AddReportComment", "Routes", new {id = comment.Id})" class="Report" onmouseover="Report(@comment.Id)" onmouseout="ResetReport(@comment.Id)">
            <img src="~/Content/Style/img/report.png" id="Report_@comment.Id" />
            @Html.Action("ReportComment", "Routes", new { id = comment.Id })
        </a>
    </div>
}
```

....

```
function LikeClick(id) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "@(Url.Action("AddLC", "Routes"))",
        dataType: "Json",
        data: { "id": id },
        success: function (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    });
}
```

and the action looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult AddLC(int id)
{
    if (check == 0)
    {
        // ...

        string message = "hi";
        return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        string message = "no";
        return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I already tried to return JavaScript content but the same result as this. As you can see I just want to show a basic alert message with custom text but I have failed for two weeks trying and finding solution on the web.

Comment: You are returning `message` but using `data` variable name in alert?

Comment: Just change `success: function (message)` to `success: function (data)`.

Comment: well yeah sorry that's my mistake from many trying. But that not solve the problem because of the action return message in a new view. what I don't want. But maybe that's the problem the "success" never happen because action redirects it to a new view.

Comment: can you post how you call the LikeClick function?

Comment: sure, updated.... and I realize that I forget to delete href so that is the reason why it redirects to a new view, so now its deleted but script doesn't do anything right now :(

Comment: Note that `async: false` has been deprecated for years; you should depend on that working any more.

Comment: The problem is you're using an anchor like a button. An anchor (`<a>`) *should* redirect you elsewhere that's its purpose. Use a `<button type="button">`.

Comment: so I tried to change <a> to a button but the result is still same after click nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally find where was the problem and as I think it was a dumb detail on what I forgot so after I look into the console in a debugger I find here an error (" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' ") so after adding jQuery it starts working. Thanks to everyone for the help and sorry for wasting your time for this.